# Move list paging buttons

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, page-layout

Is there a way to relocate the page navigation buttons from the bottom of the list to the top?  It is a hassle to scroll through 30+ items just to get to the buttons.

I read related posts that suggested using jQuery and JS code in a CEWP OR doing something with the XSLT.

I'm looking to place the page navigator buttons next to the search bar.  The imgur link shows the exact location I'm trying to put the buttons in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7I1R.jpg

How could I get the paging buttons there?  And is there a way to still keep buttons at the bottom of the list while placing new buttons at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can clone the Navigation Bar as below. Just run the code after page load

```
jQuery('#scriptPagingWPQ1').clone().appendTo('.ms-csrlistview-controldiv');
```

The problem with this is it stops asynchronous pagination and uses a full page refresh as it moves between pages.

Another option is to use JSLink and attach it to the list view webpart. Then create your own navigation.